# Electron: Get current BrowserWindow ID from AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I am dealing with multiple electron windows and would like to get the current BrowserWindow ID to persist content after page reloads. How can I get the current window ID *without* using `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()`? I would simply like to access the window ID to use during page reloads to identify which content belongs to which window.

Comment: What exactly is your reasoning behind not using [BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#browserwindowgetallwindows) or [BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow)?